# Finding the email/account associated with a Google Analytics "UA-XXXXXX-X" id?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I set up Google Analytics for a client some time ago, so the tracking code is installed.   I can't for the life of me find which email account I used to set it up, so now I can't access the stats.  We haven't actually wanted to track anything until now.

Is it possible to somehow find out what email/Google account is associated with the `UA-XXXXXXX-X` id?

Comment: Do you have a list of possible email/password combinations it could be?

Answer (score 18):

Contact Google support.  You cannot reverse engineer it, as that would be a large security hole.

[Mitch Satchwell](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/52197/mitch-satchwell) reported in the comments that he had success by contacting Google support:

> I had the same issue and was initially put off by the negative comments on this answer but contacted Google anyway (analytics screen, settings cog, help). To my surprise they were very helpful. They emailed the person the account belonged to and asked them to make contact with me. They also provided the opportunity to prove ownership by uploading a txt file to the website in question.

Comment: I'm not sure Google Support is going to be willing to do anything if the user doesn't have access to the original email account... again, a security hole.

Comment: He didn't say he doesn't have access, he just can't remember which one he used.  He may be able to have them send a reset password to whichever one it is.

Comment: I know he didn't say he didn't have access... that's why I said "if".

Comment: If this is the case, gio, you may be able to show proof of owning the domain or something.  I've never queried Google, but they are normally pretty hard to get stuff out of (from what I read/hear).

Comment: yeah, i contacted them (harder than i thought) and we'll see. I don't hold high hopes. The email used will be one we can access, I just can't remember what we used! so if they can tell us the address & send a reset pass link to it, that would be enough.

Comment: @gio:  Curious, how many different addresses could it be?  I'd keep trying different ones until a password reset comes through... that may be less painful than dealing with Google.

Comment: I had the same issue and was initially put off by the negative comments on this answer but contacted Google anyway (analytics screen, settings cog, help). To my surprise they were very helpful. They emailed the person the account belonged to and asked them to make contact with me. They also provided the opportunity to prove ownership by uploading a txt file to the website in question.

Comment: This was really useful.  They now allow you to upload a `.txt` file to the domain and get access.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can contact Google or you can post in their product forum [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/Ij9ai349tAA).

I too had issues with one of my companies' Google Analytics Accounts. Sadly, we lost the email used in making the Google Analytics account. As long as you have at least some information on your Google Analytics account, the Google support team can help.