# Request to join a Google analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to as to request someone elses google analytics account, if i dont know who the owner/manager is? or find out who that is via UA-id?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently not a feature to request access, or to find a Google account from an ID. [Google themselves can help with the latter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13121/finding-the-email-account-associated-with-a-google-analytics-ua-xxxxxx-x-id) but it's meant for reasons other than just wanting to be 'let in'.

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose? Are you the owner? New web master? Please let us know.

If you don't know the owner/manager, in short you will not get access to Google Analytics for the particular site(s) you have in mind.

Also, you will not be able to obtain Google Analytics site owner information with the UA-id alone. The current Google Analytics owner must give you permissions via Admin toolset. If you need to recover a site or add a site you must create a new Google Analytics usage ID and verify site/domain ownership via meta tag insertion or CName Record at Google's request along with your Gmail account information.

Comment: Some hosts and such allow us to request access by entering our client's info, including email address. This makes it really easy @dvnkiss for them to grant us access. I think that's all Andy was asking: does GA have a similar feature. It would be super nice for less-than-savvy clients.